# how to do "remember me" login option in laravel?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

so what i am working on is when i check the **remember me** checkbox the user when logout the form (username and password) remember the user data like that : [image]

**so this is my code it not works :(**

```
// create our user data for the authentication
        $userdata = array(
                'email'     => Input::get('email'),
                'password'  => Input::get('password')
        );

        // attempt to do the login
        if (Auth::attempt($userdata, true)) {

            Session::flash('message', array('body'=>trans('login-signup.welcome'), 'type'=>'success'));
            return Redirect::to('/');

    }
```

Comment: Using Auth - did you made sure that the table users has a 'remember_me' column for the token ?

Answer (score 7):

Use Cookies

> cookie, is a small piece of data sent from a website and stored in a user's web browser while the user is browsing that website. Every time the user loads the website, the browser sends the cookie back to the server to notify the website of the user's previous activity

To create:

```
$response->withCookie(Cookie::make('name', 'value', $minutes));
```

To retrieve

```
$value = Cookie::get('name');
```

**Your question is not to remember the user login.. The question is how to fill the inputs based on saved auth information. You can do that if you print the authentication values in the input value attribute while loading the page.**

[larval Cookies Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#cookies)

Also Laravel has it's own implementation of "Remember Me"

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password), true))
{
// The user is being remembered...
}

if (Auth::viaRemember())
{
//
}
```

More information about ["Authenticating A User And "Remembering" Them"](http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users)

Answer (score 2):

```
public function validate() 
{
    // set the remember me cookie if the user check the box
    $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;

    // attempt to do the login
    $auth = Auth::attempt(
        [
            'username'  => strtolower(Input::get('username')),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')    
        ], $remember
    );
    if ($ auth) {
        return Redirect::to('home');
    } else {
        // validation not successful, send back to form 
        return Redirect::to('/')
            ->with Input(Input::except('password'))
            ->with('flash_notice', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect.');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$remember = true;
Auth::login($user, $remember);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remember the login by setting **`Cookie`**. The cookie will be stored in browser storage. it is a small piece of data sent from a website and stored in a user's web browser while the user is browsing a particular website. Every time the user loads the website, the browser sends the cookie back to the server to notify the website of the user's previous activity. In Laravel, you can set the cookie as,

```php
$response->withCookie(Cookie::make('COOKIE_NAME', 'COOKIE_VALUE', $minutes));
//or
back()->->withCookie(Cookie::make('COOKIE_NAME', 'COOKIE_VALUE', $minutes))
```

if you want to set cookie from middleware, here is the way

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->withCookie(Cookie::make('COOKIE_NAME', 'COOKIE_VALUE', $minutes))
}
```

You can either create/retrieve the cookie by **`Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie`** class or you can use the laravel's global **`cookie()`** helper function.

To retrieve the cookie,

```php
$value = Cookie::get('COOKIE_NAME');
//or
$request->cookie('COOKIE_NAME')
```

> Remember, Laravel encrypts cookie by default. The middleware **`EncryptCookies`** is responsible to encrypting cookies. You will get `null` on retrieval of such cookies. Disabling/Removing the `EncryptCookies` middleware is not the solution.

you can except the cookie from being encrypted as follow,

```php
protected $except = [
    'COOKIE_NAME',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$remember = request('remember');
if (auth()->guard('admin')->attempt(request(['email', 'password']), 
$remember)) {
    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.